# No connectivity with the server...The file '................' can't be opened because the server couldn't be contracted

Tags: webdav

OS X 10.12.6 with Chrome (70.0.3538.0) and Office for Mac 2011 (14.7.7) and attempting to edit a document with WebDAV using it Hit Ajax Library (2.0.1773.0) & WebDAV Server (4.0.2416.0) returns this error "No connectivity with the server...The file 'https://................' can't be opened because the server couldn't be contracted" and the file is not opened to edit...when connecting to a server using HTTPS but connecting to another server using the same it Hit software using HTTP opens the document, allows editing and saving back to the server.

This command was run with Terminal (defaults -currentHost write com.microsoft.registrationDB hkey_current_user\hkey_local_machine\software\microsoft\office\14.0\common\internet\basicauthlevel -int 2)

What other setting do I need to change on OS X to allow itHit Ajax Library (2.0.1773.0) & WebDAV Server (4.0.2416.0) to use both http and https connection to the web site...

Comment: Can you open the url in a browser? Are you using a proper SSL certificate or are you self-signing?

Comment: the SSL certification is from Network Solutions...It is not self-signing...I am able to open the document using the link in a new browser tab...One thing to note is that when I click on the icon to edit the document, the Open Microsoft Word prompt is displayed, I choose Open, the Word 2011 splash screen displays then the error message is displayed...The web site uses Forms Authentication...